# How to encode the column which has more than 50 categories

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

How to encode the column which has more than 50 categories

can we use one hot coding ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great blogpost: https://towardsdatascience.com/benchmarking-categorical-encoders-9c322bd77ee8

Basically, there are the following ways of encoding:

- basic label encoding - simply replacing by numbers
- one hot encoding (can be used with 50 categories, it is okay)
- lots of ways to use numerical encoding: frequency, mean target, and many others

Comment: What about bucketizer or factorize method

Comment: As far as I know these methods do the opposite: they convert numerical variables into categorical.